# Veins_Inet example : omnet ++

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet, sumo

In the **veins_inet example in omnet ++** , i need to send the message ( accident ) to **only some vehicles , not to all of them** , which means i don't want to send the message in broadcast but i want to send it to **specific vehicles at a simulation time that i choose** ? Does anyone know how to do that ? I wonder if i should change the code in  **VeinsInetSampleApplication.cc** ?? maybe i have to change **the sendPacket method** but i don't know how to do it ! i spent days trying to change the destination address , i used the senddirect () function , i added gates but i got a lot of errors ! Can you help me please ? :

Here is the code related to my issue from the example ( this is the code that sends the message in broadcast to all the vehicles without any changes ) , **this is not the whole code but i chose from each class some lines that i think are related to my problem**  :

**At the VeinsInetSampleApplication.cc :**

```
// host[0] should stop at t=37s
                           /*if (getParentModule()->getIndex() == 4) {
                               auto callback = [this]() {
                                   getParentModule()->getDisplayString().setTagArg("i", 1, "yellow");

                                   traciVehicle->setSpeed(0);

                                   auto payload = makeShared<VeinsInetSampleMessage>();
                                   payload->setChunkLength(B(500));
                                   payload->setRoadId(traciVehicle->getRoadId().c_str());
                                   timestampPayload(payload);

                                   auto packet = createPacket("accident");
                                   packet->insertAtBack(payload);
                                   sendPacket(std::move(packet));

                                   // host should continue after 40s
                                   auto callback = [this]() {
                                       traciVehicle->setSpeed(-1);
                                   };

                                   timerManager.create(veins::TimerSpecification(callback).oneshotIn(SimTime(40, SIMTIME_S)));
                               };

                               timerManager.create(veins::TimerSpecification(callback).oneshotAt(SimTime(37, SIMTIME_S)));
                           }
```

**The sendPacketMethod At the veinsInetApplicationBase.cc :**

```
void VeinsInetApplicationBase::sendPacket(std::unique_ptr<inet::Packet> pk)
{
    emit(packetSentSignal, pk.get());
    socket.sendTo(pk.release(), destAddress, portNumber);
}
```

**At the veinsInetApplicationBase.h :**

```
inet::L3Address destAddress;
    const int portNumber = 9001;
```

**At the veinsInetApplicationBase.cc :**

```
 L3AddressResolver().tryResolve("224.0.0.1", destAddress);
    ASSERT(!destAddress.isUnspecified());

    socket.setOutputGate(gate("socketOut"));
    socket.bind(L3Address(), portNumber);
```

**At Scenario.ned :**

```
node[0]: VeinsInetCar ;
```

And here i don't understand **why is it only node[0] that is defined ?** i have 6 nodes in my simulation , how can i specify the nodes i want to send the message to because i don't want to send it to all of the nodes , i just want to send my message to those that are distanced less than 500 m from the vehicle sending the message ? how to specify the destination addresses of the nodes based on the distance ? ( because i work with 802.11p)

**Finally **At the the omnet.ini** :**

```
[General]
network = Scenario
sim-time-limit = 140s
debug-on-errors = true
cmdenv-express-mode = true
image-path = ../../../../images

# UDPBasicApp
*.node[*].numApps = 1
*.node[*].app[0].typename = "mywork.veins_inet.VeinsInetSampleApplication"
*.node[*].app[0].interface = "wlan0"

# Ieee80211Interface
*.node[*].wlan[0].opMode = "p"
*.node[*].wlan[0].radio.typename = "Ieee80211DimensionalRadio"
*.node[*].wlan[0].radio.bandName = "5.9 GHz"
*.node[*].wlan[0].radio.channelNumber = 6
*.node[*].wlan[0].radio.transmitter.power = 20mW
*.node[*].wlan[0].radio.bandwidth = 10 MHz
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.typename = "AttachedMobility"
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.mobilityModule = "^.^.^.^.mobility"
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.offsetX = -2.5m
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.offsetZ = 1.5m
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.constraintAreaMaxX = 0m
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.constraintAreaMaxY = 0m
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.constraintAreaMaxZ = 0m

# HostAutoConfigurator
*.node[*].ipv4.configurator.typename = "HostAutoConfigurator"
*.node[*].ipv4.configurator.interfaces = "wlan0"
*.node[*].ipv4.configurator.mcastGroups = "224.0.0.1"


# VeinsInetMobility
*.node[*].mobility.typename = "VeinsInetMobility"

# VeinsInetManager
*.manager.updateInterval = 0.1s
*.manager.host = "localhost"
*.manager.port = 9999
*.manager.autoShutdown = true
*.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("enetcom.launchd.xml")
*.manager.moduleType = "mywork.veins_inet.VeinsInetCar"

# PhysicalEnvironment
*.physicalEnvironment.config = xmldoc("obstacles.xml")
*.radioMedium.obstacleLoss.typename = "IdealObstacleLoss"

# Misc
**.vector-recording = true
```

Now what i need to know is which lines from these lines i have to change and how shall i change them in order to make the message sent only to some vehicles i choose by myself in the simulation not to all the vehicles around ?? Please help me ! Thank you so much in advance !

Comment: You are using simulation modules of The INET Framework for simulating radio communication. Were you able to achieve what you want in a simple simulation that uses only INET Framework modules?

Comment: No sir , the problem isn't solved , i actually didn't know how to send the message to only some specific vehicles , once a vehicle sends an alert/a message , all the vehicles around receive the message and i just want some vehicles from the vector of vehicles declared to receive my message , any idea how to do that please ?

Comment: As you are writing a simulation model of a real-life system, you will need to start by thinking about how this would be done in real life. Would you use directional antennas? Beam forming? Many point-to-point connections using TCP? An IP multicast group? Only then will it make sense to think about how to build the simulation model.